# How to eliminate space between panels in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a series of panels created using the following markup:

```
<div class="container-fluid">

    <!-- Repeated For Each Panel-->
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="panel panel-info">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">Name</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                Other info
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    ...
</div>
```

Since the content of the panels is variable in length, the result is:
[image: Panels with gaps]

(note that the names are randomly generated test data)

How can I eliminate the extra space between the panels -- for example the gap between the items in the first column -- so that all of the panels have an even amount of space between them no matter how much content is in each panel.

Note that I would like to retain the three column layout.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You apparently want a Pinterest-like layout. This is typically accomplished using [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) (or other such similar JavaScript libraries).

Comment: So there is no way to accomplish that with just using bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

You should use multiple `.row`'s.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            ....
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            ....
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            ....
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            ....
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            ....
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            ....
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I don't think that will accomplish what I want. Wouldn't this make the top of each panel in a row begin at the same height? I would like each item to be the same distance from the panel above it.